# Relationship between Bot tokens and workspace

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have created my first slack app and I'm about to try and publish it to the app directory.

In my app, when I try to perform API calls like `api/views.publish` or `/api/views.open`, I use the `Bot User OAuth Token` found in `OAuth & Permission` in my app settings page.

The part that I'm confused by is the token I have universal for all workspaces that download the app, or will it be unique per workspace that installs it?

If it is not universal, then how would I go about to programmatically retrieve the bot token for each workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make sure your app handles Oauth. Everytime a different workspace installs your app they'll need to be taken through an oauth flow where your app will be granted tokens associated with that specific workspace.
https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2